# Множественное пользовательское поле

Tags: php, битрикс

Как добавить значение в множественное пользовательское поле типа строка в свойства пользователя? Если так, то массив перезаписывается, а мне нужно чтобы добавлялось в массив.

```
$user = new  CUser;   
$fields = Array( 
"UF_XXX" => array($GLOBALS['XXX'])); 
$user ->Update($UserID,$fields);
```

Comment: Добавить значения так как вы хотите нельзя, такого функционала нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить значение нельзя, надо получить текущее значение, добавить нужные данные к ним, и записать.